# JAVA: Wrong ip in response via proxy

Tags: java, url, proxy, ip, response

Have this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "177.40.136.238");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

    // Next connection will be through proxy.
    try {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://ip.jsontest.com/");
        while (true) {
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Now, let's 'unset' the proxy.
    System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
}
```

When i get ip in console, it is not like ip of setted proxy (it is ip of my local station). What i did wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "get ip in console"?

Comment: What is the result when you access that URL in browser?

Comment: "get ip in console" mean that i get respons looks like {"ip": "my.local.ip.address"} same like in browser

Answer (score 0):

So, problem was with public proxy witch doesn't hide your request information. All we need to do - send our request through anonymous proxies.